# How to skip splashscreen when app is already running in background

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have a customer's requirement to provide the splash-screen with animation for an application, but skip the splash-screen when app is already running in background and user starts it again using the app's icon. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: use shared preferences.

Answer (score 4):

Easy. Create static boolean variable in Application's (singleton) class. And set it to TRUE from Service. And check it inside Activity.onCreate().

Comment: Which Service do you refer to? I haven't mentioned any.

Comment: What you mind 'running in background'? Are you run service? If your app not contains service you may set variable to true in Activity.onCreate when it run first time. (sorry for my English)

Comment: I mean the following scenario: 1. User starts app first time. 2. User presses "Home" button to send app to background. 3. User launches app again using its icon.

Comment: Create static variable 'flag' in StartActivity. Set 'flag=true' in END  path of StartActivity.onCreate(). Check in START path 'if(flag == false) runsplachscreen();' in StartActivity.onCreate() or StartActivity.onRestore().

Answer (score 1):

I know a bit lengthy process but I am not sure if you would like it or not.

Step 1 :set up a global variable by extending application class 
(the life of global variable is not dependent on the activity but instead it is dependent on the application.

Step 2: use that global variable as a flag .Reset that global variable to 1(or whatever) if the activity has started.

Step 3: check the value of the global variable and then decide if you would like to display the splash screen or not

Answer (score 0):

I created a tutorial for a View based splash screen.  If you added some kind of parameter-logic to track if the application is already loaded could easily create the feature you are describing.

You can find the [tutorial here](http://androiddev101.com/episode-7easy-splash-good-boy/)